# How to find the same value in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I need your help, I ve an array like below

```
[["A","Orange"],["B","Orange"],["C","Orange"],["D","Orange"],["E","Apple"],["F","Mango"],["G","Banana"]]
```

I wanna find the same fruits so that the result would be

```
A - D: Orange, E: Apple, F: mango, G Banana
```

how do i search the same fruits in multi array? thanks.

Comment: Create a `foreach` loop

Comment: i have create one, but then im stuck how to match the same fruit's name? @u_mulder

Comment: Add name to array if it doesn't exists there.

Comment: can u gimme an example? i dont understand sir @u_mulder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the fruit name as a key, and the key as value of the result.

```
foreach($fruits as $fruit)
{
  $o[$fruit[1]][] = $fruit[0];
}
```

test code:

```
<?php
$fruits = [["A","Orange"],["B","Orange"],["C","Orange"],["D","Orange"],["E","Apple"],["F","Mango"],["G","Banana"]];
foreach($fruits as $fruit)
{
  $o[$fruit[1]][] = $fruit[0];
}
var_dump($o);
```

output:

```
ei@localhost:~$ php test.php
array(4) {
  ["Orange"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "A"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "B"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "C"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "D"
  }
  ["Apple"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "E"
  }
  ["Mango"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "F"
  }
  ["Banana"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "G"
  }
}
```

edited:

```
<?php
$fruits = [["A","Orange"],["B","Orange"],["C","Orange"],["D","Orange"],["E","Apple"],["F","Mango"],["G","Banana"]];
$fruits2 = [["A","Orange"],["C","Orange"],["D","Orange"],["E","Apple"],["F","Mango"],["G","Banana"]];
foreach($fruits2 as $fruit)
{
  $o[$fruit[1]][] = $fruit[0];
}
$o = array_map(function($v){
  $str = '';
  $pre = '';
  $isInSequence = false;
  $item = '';
  foreach($v as $item)
  {
    if($pre != '')
    {
        if(ord($pre) == ord($item) - 1)
        {
            $isInSequence = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if($isInSequence)
                $str = $str . '-';
            else
                $str = $str . ',' . $item;
            $isInSequence = false;
        }
    }
    else
        $str = $str.$item;
    $pre = $item;
  }
  if($isInSequence)
  {
      $str = $str . '-' . $item;
  }
  return $str;
}, $o);
var_dump($o);
```

output:

```
ei@localhost:~$ php test.php
array(4) {
  ["Orange"]=>
  string(5) "A,C-D"
  ["Apple"]=>
  string(1) "E"
  ["Mango"]=>
  string(1) "F"
  ["Banana"]=>
  string(1) "G"
}
```

Comment: u cant do it, it would be illegal offset type

Comment: how could it be sir?, i mean, does the array find it automatically? please explain it to me sir.

Comment: sir, how d i represent the result look like this `A - D: Orange, E: Apple, F: mango, G Banana`

Comment: Yeah, when the duplicated values key is in sequence, it's easy. But when the duplicate is now in sequence, what the output should be?

Comment: for example, the A, C, D have same Orange, what the output should be:

Comment: it would be A, C-D, what algorithm to make it sir?

Comment: for example, A, E F G is orange and B, C, D is Banana so it would be A, E-G: Orange, B-D: Banana

Comment: actually it's not 26 items, but only  7 items which are A, B, C, D ,E. F, G

Comment: aye aye sir, i ll wait it while im trying to solve the case.

Comment: thank you so much sir, it solves my problem :D:D #added